# "To try oneself in something" template usage

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

For example,

> I'd like to try myself in farming.

Is this grammatically correct? I want to express that I never have done farming before and wish to begin doing it.

Comment: The first problem is semantic. This isn't idiomatic. Jon Hanna's answer gives the natural and normal native speaker English expression for what your sentence means. If you delete "myself in", you've got a perfectly grammatical and idiomatic expression that means the same as "I'd like to try my hand at farming" and what your sentence wants to say. Which sentence you choose is a matter of style, not grammar. While grammar **can** make a difference, semantics and idiomaticity are far more important for clear communication and easy understanding.

Answer (score 3):

To try oneself normally means to do something for the challenge, for how that tests ones mettle and you learn from the experience. That seems to go a bit beyond what you describe in the question.

There's an idiom "to try one's hand at", that would be appropriate here:

> I'd like to try my hand at farming.

It means exactly what you describe in your question - you haven't done it before, and you like to try and see how you fared.

Comment: You could also *give farming a go/try*.